# PHP PEAR send_mail Failed to set sender with name and email

Tags: php, email, pear, sendmail

I'm tryng to send an email with this script

```
$to = 'example@example.com';
$headers['To'] = $to;
$headers['From'] = '"My Name" <examlpe@example.com>';
$headers['Return-Path'] = 'examlpe@example.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Subject';

$auth = array('host' => MAIL_HOST, 'auth' => true, 'username' => MAIL_USER, 'password' => MAIL_PASS);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $auth);
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);

if (PEAR::isError($mail))
    echo('<p>PEAR mail: '.$mail->getMessage().'</p>');
else
    echo('<p>PEAR mail: Message successfully sent!</p>');
```

But I got the following message:

```
Failed to set sender: "My Name" <example@example.com> [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 501, response: <"My Name" <example@example.com>>: "@" or "." expected after ""My Name"")]
```

When I make the from field like this:

```
$headers['From'] = 'examlpe@example.com';
```

It works fine and I receive the email.

How can I send an email with the name of the sender?

Comment: Did you try it quoteless? `My Name <example@example.com>` is a valid mailbox too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return-Path and Reply-To are not the same.

Return-Path: If you want to override the envelope sender of the email, set the Return-Path header and that value will be used instead of the value of the From: header (From PEAR website). You cannot set name for Return-Path, just an email address.

Reply-To: Makes the recipient reply to this address. You can set a name and an email address.

So replace Return-Path by Reply-To and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the email address in the From. I suggest you should add "Reply-To" header and provide the email address there and in From just specify Name.

Comment: I need to the email address in the From because without that, it won't send. But my mistake was I though Return-Path was Reply-To and it causes an error. When I replace Return-Path by Reply-To, it works.